# API key not appending to ReverseGeocode request

Tags: tomtom, tomtom-android-sdk

For some reason my API key doesn’t seem to be added to my reverse Geocode request.

[image]

The key is correctly in my info.plist , I’ve tried adding every other key to my plist also but this still isn’t working.

Here is the request im attempting

```
var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
coordinate.latitude = 54.966682
coordinate.longitude = -7.730234

let query = TTReverseGeocoderQueryBuilder.create(with: coordinate).withReturnSpeedLimit(true)
    .build()
reverseGeocoder.reverseGeocoder(with: query)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks
Oliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks fine. The API key is hidden inside logs.

Note that using `reverseGeocoder(with: query)` method you need to conform to the `TTReverseGeocoderDelegate` protocol in order to get the results out.
It can be easily done by adding a few lines of code:

```
import TomTomOnlineSDKSearch
import TomTomOnlineSDKRouting

class MainViewController: UIViewController, TTReverseGeocoderDelegate {
(...)
let tomtomRGeoAPI = TTReverseGeocoder()

func reverseGeocoder(_ reverseGeocoder: TTReverseGeocoder, completedWith response: TTReverseGeocoderResponse) {
    NSLog("success")
}

func reverseGeocoder(_ reverseGeocoder: TTReverseGeocoder, failedWithError error: TTResponseError) {
    NSLog("error")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tomtomRevGeoAPI.delegate = self

    var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    coordinate.latitude = 54.966682
    coordinate.longitude = -7.730234

    let query = TTReverseGeocoderQueryBuilder.create(with: coordinate).withReturnSpeedLimit(true)
        .build()
    self.tomtomRevGeoAPI.reverseGeocoder(with: query)
}
(...)
```

Regards, 
Mateusz